# Laravel : Adicionar campos em duas tabelas (Tabelas Relacionadas)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Estou com um problema no Laravel onde tenho duas tabelas relacionadas.

Tenho um formulario para a tabela1 (Capitulo) e um formulario para a tabela2 (documentacao)

Consigo adicionar "Capitulos" sem interferir com a outra tabela. Mas quando tento adicionar dados no formulario documentacao dá erro e diz que o parametro da tabela capitulo está vazio.

Tenho o seguinte controller :

```
public function insert(Request $request){
   
    $tabela = new capitulo();
    $tabela->capitulo = $request->capitulo;

    $itens = capitulo::where('capitulo', '=', $request->capitulo)->count(); 
    if($itens > 0){
        echo "<script language='javascript'> window.alert('Já existe um capitulo com esse nome!') </script>";
        return view('gestao-documental');
       //return redirect()->route('GestaoDocumental');
    }

    $tabela->save();
  


    return redirect()->route('documentacao.index');
}


public function insert2(Request $request){
   
           //--------------------------------------------------

           $doc = new documentacao();
           $doc->id_capitulo = $request->id_capitulo;
           $doc->nome_ficheiro = $request->nome_ficheiro;
   
           if ($request->file('ficheiro')->isValid()){
               $request->file('ficheiro')->store('ficheiro/documentacao');    
           }
           //$doc->ficheiro = $request->file(ficheiro);
           $doc->versao = $request->versao;
           $doc->data_ultima_alteracao = $request->versao; 
   
   
           //dd($request->file('ficheiro')->isValid());
   
   
           $doc = documentacao::where('nome_ficheiro', '=', $request->nome_ficheiro)->count(); 
           if($doc > 0){
               echo "<script language='javascript'> window.alert('Já existe um capitulo com esse nome!') </script>";
               return view('gestao-documental');
              //return redirect()->route('GestaoDocumental');
           }
   
   
           
           
           $doc->save();
    
    return redirect()->route('GestaoDocumental');
}
```

EDIT:
Neste momento o erro que ocorre é SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'capitulo' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `capitulos` (`capitulo`) values (?))

A tabela "principal" ´o titulo e dentro do titulo existem varios "documentos".

Ao inserir nos documentos obriga que a tabela titulo esteja preenchida

MODEL capitulo:

```
    class capitulo extends Model
     {
     public $timestamps = false;
     use HasFactory;

      public function documentos() {

     return $this->hasMany(documentacao::class,'id_capitulo');
     }
}
```

MODEL Documentacao:

```
class documentacao extends Model
{
  public $timestamps = false;
  use HasFactory;
}
```

VIEW:

```
  <form id="form-perfil" method="POST" action="{{route('documentacao.insert2')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf

                                        <div class="modal-body">

                        
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label >Capitulo Associado</label>
                                    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                                        <option selected>Escolher Capitulo</option>
                                        @foreach($capitulos as $cap)
                                        <option class="form-control" id="id_capitulo" name="id_capitulo"> {{$cap->capitulo}}</option>
                                        @endforeach 
                                        </select>
                                        <input value="" type="text" class="form-control" id="id_capitulo" name="id_capitulo" placeholder="Capitulo">
                                    </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label >Nome Ficheiro</label>
                                    <input value="" type="text" class="form-control" id="nome_ficheiro" name="nome_ficheiro" placeholder="Nome Ficheiro">
                                </div>

                                
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label >Adicionar Ficheiro</label>
                                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="ficheiro" id="ficheiro" />
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label >Versão</label>
                                <input value="" min="1"  value="1" step="0.1" type="number" class="form-control" id="versao" name="versao" placeholder="Versão">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label >Data alteração</label>
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="data_ultima_alteracao" name="data_ultima_alteracao">
                                </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">

                        <button type="button" id="btn-fechar" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                        <button type="submit" name="btn-salvar-perfil" id="btn-salvar-perfil" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Poderia explicar porque aqui `$doc = documentacao::where('nome_ficheiro', '=', $request->nome_ficheiro)->count();` você sobrescreve `$doc` por um valor numérico sendo que ainda não salvou as modificações?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere o teste se já existe um doc para antes de iniciar a lógica de criar um novo caso não exista

```php
public function insert2(Request $request){
   
     $doc = documentacao::where('nome_ficheiro', '=', $request->nome_ficheiro)->count(); 
     if($doc > 0){
         echo "<script language='javascript'> window.alert('Já existe um capitulo com esse nome!') </script>";
         return view('gestao-documental');
        //return redirect()->route('GestaoDocumental');
     }


    //--------------------------------------------------

    $doc = new documentacao();
    $doc->id_capitulo = $request->id_capitulo;
    $doc->nome_ficheiro = $request->nome_ficheiro;
   
    if ($request->file('ficheiro')->isValid()){
        $request->file('ficheiro')->store('ficheiro/documentacao');    
    }
    //$doc->ficheiro = $request->file(ficheiro);
    $doc->versao = $request->versao;
    $doc->data_ultima_alteracao = $request->versao; 
   
   
    //dd($request->file('ficheiro')->isValid());
   
          
           
    $doc->save();
    
    return redirect()->route('GestaoDocumental');
}
```

EDIT para resolver a view

Abaixo mostro como corrigir o problema da View, que não está "identificando" o capítulo. Isto é por quê você não está informando no option do select qual o valor daquela seleção

```php
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Capitulo Associado</label>
   <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="id_capitulo">
      <option selected>Escolher Capitulo</option>
      @foreach($capitulos as $cap)
         <option class="form-control" value="{{$cap->id}}"> {{$cap->capitulo}}</option>
      @endforeach 
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'capitulo' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `capitulos` (`capitulo`) values (?)) tenho este erro

Comment: o certo no seu caso não é inserir no mesmo método do controller o capítulo e a documentação na sequência? Veja, fica difícil dar uma ajuda melhor se não informar detalhes como a modelagem do banco ou um screenshot da tela

Comment: Vou colocar como está atualmente os meus models. Dentro do meu controller estou a tentar guardar em duas tabelas diferentes que estão relacionadas. 
Quando executo o insert2, pede-me sempre o campo da outra tabela

Comment: Mas nesse código aqui na questão vc não tem nenhum Capitulo->save() por exemplo para dar erro "insert into capitulos" .... não estou conseguindo enxergar o erro

Comment: Diria que está a dar esse erro por as tabelas estarem relacionadas. Porque no código não deveria dar esse erro. Um capítulo pode ter N documentos

Comment: select
  count(*) as aggregate
from
  `capitulos`
where
  `capitulo` is null
tenho este erro no debug

Comment: A questão é que o err de insert cannot be null em um insert into capitulos, quer dizer q vc está tentando inserir na tabela capítulos um valor nulo no campo capítulo, o qual não pode ser nulo, mas na função insert2 vc não tem, ao menos não aqui na pergunta, um insert para a tabela capitulos, então estou com problemas em lhe auxiliar ... precisaria ver o código da blade, rota q está chamando e esquema do banco de dados, que é diferente de código php do modelo

Comment: Tenho 2 problemas.. Na View (que acabei de colocar aqui) quando faço o @foreach o name ID_capitulo não passa para o controller . E quando tento guardar na tabela não necessita de fazer nenhuma referencia a tabela "principal"

Comment: Editei a resposta com a correção na Blade, funcionando, agradeço marcar a resposta como correta e dar um up nela